# Renew Spousal Visa UK

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa

just over two years ago, I, a British citizen married and successfully applied for a spousal visa for my Mexican wife. According to her biometic card, (residence permit - leave to remain) it will expire in late august 2019.

When we applied for the spousal visa two years ago, we spent a hefty sum on legal fees and had to take a day off work to attend the fast-track service in Croyden. Ideally, when renewing the spousal visa, we'd like to do so as cheaply as possible, hopefully without the assistance of lawyers.

I have a couple of questions

1. Am I correct in thinking that the process can be done entirely online/by post, rather than having to attend in person?
2. What evidence of our relationship will be needed?
3. How soon in advance of the August deadline do we need to start doing things? We don't want to leave it too late, but I also presume that it's possible to attempt to renew the spousal visa 'too early'.

Many thanks

Comment: I can answer the third question.

I went for 6 months before my expiry and successfully got renewed. What i was told is you can go even earlier. But please note that you need to stay for 5 years before you can apply for ILR. So you don't want to go too early, so that you end up requiring one more extension.

Comment: Q2 You will need evidence of continuing co-habitation, such as utility bills, medical letters, HMRC letters and bank statements that are in joint names. A minimum of 6 different pieces of evidence are required covering the 2-year pre-application period.